# Как подсчитать с помощью конвейера команд количество блочных устройств ввода-вывода, доступных в системе? [Linux/Bash]

Tags: linux, bash

Как подсчитать с помощью конвейера команд количество блочных устройств ввода-вывода, доступных в системе? Linux (bash)

Answer (score 1):

если саму методику получения **правильного** списка блочных устройств оставить на совести преподавателя, задающего столь **нетривиальные** вопросы, и ограничиться, исключительно для илллюстрации, каким-нибудь банальным содержимым каталога `/sys/block`, то остаётся три достаточно неочевидные задачи:

1. как получить список содержимого каталога **исключительно** средствами программы *bash*?
2. как подсчитать количество строк (или слов) **исключительно** теми же средствами?
3. куда? ну куда??? куда же здесь впихнуть ещё и конвейер?

---

ну что же, попробуем.

1. тут достаточно просто, если принять во внимание, что `echo` является **встроенной** командой программы *bash*:

   ```
   $ echo /sys/block/*
   ```
2. тут возможно множество вариантов. наиболее простые, без использования циклов:

   1. поместить список в массив и вывести длину массива:

      ```
      $ array=($(echo /sys/block/*)); echo ${#array[@]}
      ```
   2. или поместить список в массив аргументов с помощью (встроенной!) команды `set` и вывести его длину:

      ```
      $ set /sys/block/*; echo $#
      ```
3. впихивание конвейера - это, пожалуй, самая сложная часть. пока додумался только до такой перенагруженной конструкции с использованием (встроенной!) команды `read`:

   ```
   $ echo /sys/block/* | ( read -a array; echo ${#array[@]} )
   ```

   подумаю на досуге. может быть удастся упростить.

Comment: `ls -l /sys/block | wc -l` ?

Comment: да, я помню, что `wc` - это `coreutils`, а не `built-in bash`, но мне кажется, что задача тут проще...

Comment: @defrag, возможно, в задании и была оговорка про использование **других** программ. в интерпретации же автора вопроса речь только об **одной** программе.